# What should I do after crashing when writing into a sqlite db (iOS)?

Tags: ios, database, sqlite

If an app crashes when writing into a sqlite db (or CoreData), sometimes the db file will be broken, after which initialisation of the db may fail to open.

What I'm doing now is deleting the db file if it fails to open, and copying a new one to be used.

I'm wondering what's the **BEST WAY** to deal with such situation?

Comment: According to this page -> http://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html (Section 2.1) SQLite should automatically handle a power failure or crash by rolling back whatever did not finish successfully.  More info in section 4 of this page http://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the atomic commit nature of SQLite, you should never experience database corruption, if you are, it could be due to enabling features such as "Write Caching" within iOS or in the hard drive itself, or could possibly even be caused by hardware failure.

SQLite maintains a journal file to rollback commits and return the database to a consistent state in the event of a power failure or other abrupt shutdown. If corruption occurs, it means that the OS responded to SQLite stating a write operation had completed when in actuality, it wasn't physically committed to the media yet. Please ensure Write Caching is disabled when using it in your App. For more information, please see the SQLite [Atomic Commit reference](http://www.sqlite.org/atomiccommit.html).

Otherwise the common method people seem to "repair" a SQlite DB is to `.dump` the DB file into another. Like so `echo ".dump" | sqlite old.db | sqlite new.db`

Hope this helps...

[[source]](http://random.kakaopor.hu/how-to-repair-an-sqlite-database)